# How to ensure MySQL selects do not interfere?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have a table in my MySQL DB which basically contains "cron"-like tasks. Basically a user visits a page and the script (php) checks the DB cron table, gets the latest 5 results that are "available" and executes the scripts related to the tasks.

Only issues I foresee at the moment is that 2 users might get the same tasks. Note that currently I first run an UPDATE query which assigns 5 tasks to the current user. After that I do a SELECT query to get 5 tasks assigned to the current user and when hes done I mark the tasks as completed.

Theoretically no 2 users should ever get the same tasks but I'm uncertain. I'm simple wondering if MySQL possibly has a build in mechanism to ensure this or if there are known methods for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html). This way you can ensure that a multi-step operation, such as [UPDATE, SELECT, UPDATE] is either wholly completed, or does not happen at all.

This is a classic [concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_%28computer_science%29) problem, it's worth reading up about concurrency and transactions in general so that you understand the principals. This will help you avoid problems down the line (there are lots of knotty problems in concurrency!).

Comment: Thanks, I have read up on transactions and as far as I can tell this only prevents data from being committed unless all queries have completed. I don't see how this could prevent other users from receiving the same db results? There's no way to tell if another user is currently working with the same results.

Comment: Hello Naatan, read the mysql manual regarding table locks, it might help you

Comment: If there are uncommitted changes, the database will put a lock on the affected rows or tables.  The lock will prevent further reads and writes of those objects until the changes are committed.

Comment: Thanks julioc, Brent & fredley. That makes sense. But an update locks the affected rows as well so then wouldnt that mean that my current implementation would be secure? Or woud you recommend using transactions either way? (Btw the table in question is an InnoDB table).

Comment: Transactions are the way to go. Table locks will work, but the granularity of locking with transactions will be optimal (it will only lock the rows it needs to lock, other operations can still happen on the rest of the table).